# Reducing Airy differential equation to Bessel equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions, airy-functions

I have to reduce the following differential equation to the Bessel equation.
$$y''+\lambda xy = 0$$
Upon seeing articles on the internet, I found that this is an Airy differential equation, which can be converted to a Bessel equation by using the substitution given in [the below answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140648/convert-airys-equation-y-xy-0-into-bessel-equation-t2u-tu).

Is there any general method by which we can predict this substitution, or do we have to brute force different substitutions to see which one works?

Comment: @Nasser Thanks, that was helpful. It would be best if you wrote this as an answer so I can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of the Bessel equation have, in first order, an asymptotic behavior at infinity of $e^{\pm ix}$, or its trigonometric versions.

The given equation has, by the WKB method, asymptotics of $\exp(\pm i\int\sqrt{λx}dx)=\exp(\pm i\frac23\sqrt{λ}x^{3/2})$. This indicates a substitution
$$
s=\frac23\sqrt{λ}x^{3/2},~~~u(s)=y(x)
$$
Then the derivatives are
$$
y'(x)=\sqrt{λx}u'(s)\\
y''(x)=λxu''(s)+\frac{\sqrt{λ}}{2\sqrt{x}}u'(s)
$$
giving the differential equation
$$
su''(s)+\frac13u'(s)+su(s)=0.
$$
At $s=0$ the equation for the leading order is $r(r-1)+\frac13r=0$ giving $r=0$ and $r=\frac23$. To center these powers around zero use $u(s)=s^{1/3}v(s)$,
$$
u'(s)=s^{1/3}v'(s)+\frac13s^{-2/3}v(s)\\
u''(s)=s^{1/3}v''(s)+\frac23s^{-2/3}v'(s)-\frac29s^{-5/3}v(s)
$$
so  that
$$
0=\left[s^2v''(s)+\frac23sv'(s)-\frac29v(s)\right]
+\frac13\left[sv'(s)+\frac13v(s)\right]+s^2v(s)
\\
0=s^2v''(s)+sv'(s)+\left[s^2-\frac19\right]v(s)
$$
This is now the requested Bessel equation. In total, and adjusting some constants,
$$
y(x)=\sqrt{x}\,v\left(\frac23\sqrt{λ}x^{3/2}\right)
$$